# ACF Pro With Polylang in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro, polylang

I have a site that has three languages (Arabic, English, and Russian). Sometimes, for no reason, the content of some Arabic and English pages becomes in Russian. Knowing that ACF Pro and polylang were used on the site, I still do not know why the content of some pages changed all of them in the Russian language (the Russian language is not It is the Default language, it is Arabic).

Can you help me figure out the problem?